# How can I find the last vowel in a string in Java?

Tags: java

I have a problem in my project.

How can I define the **last vowel** in a string in Java?
For example I have a word "Kitchen"
I want to find that the last vowel of the word "kitch**e**n" is the letter "**e**"

Comment: make at least an attempt at writing code before posting.

Comment: By searching. And remember, the JVM doesn't know what "vowel" means, you'll have to write the algorithm yourself.

Comment: at least try, I can think of a million ways to do this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is overly broad and shows no evidence of prior effort.

Comment: @user2693587 - But I bet that most of them are isomorphic :-)

Comment: @StephenC Good point but still.

Answer (score 5):

- Loop backward on the string.
- Check if current character is in a string representing the vowel combinations.

```
final String vowels = "aeiou";
for(int i = yourString.length() - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    if(vowels.indexOf(yourString.toLowerCase().charAt(i)) >= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("The last vowel is : " + yourString.charAt(i));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jean-Francois: what will happen if the last vowel is 'a'(Eg: ear)? Guess you've missed an "=" in your condition. I've corrected in my answer

Comment: @Rajesh it would work with `ear`. However you are right, for the missing `=`. I edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here is solution of your problem statement. please have a look.

```
String str = "kitchen";

        str = str.toLowerCase();

        for(int i=str.length() -1 ;i>=0;i--){

            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') {
                System.out.println(c);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    String inputWord = "ear";

    final String vowels = "aeiou";
    for(int i = inputWord.length()-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(vowels.indexOf(inputWord.toLowerCase().charAt(i))>=0)
        {
            System.out.println("The last vowel is : " + inputWord.charAt(i));
            break;
        }
    }
```